# Get all videos for a given user

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve all videos posted by a given user (eg: https://www.youtube.com/user/laliga/videos).

All the examples I've found online or the doc (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) seems to require either a playlist ID, channel ID or video ID.

Is there any way I can directly query the author's videos or am I forced to retrieve all playlists and then iterate over?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map the user name to its channelID first via the YouTube API like so:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=USER_NAME&part=id&key=API_KEY

Full docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Then you can make a [Videos:List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with that channelID to get the videos.

Answer (score 0):

1)take your google key id and channel id and put inside below url
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=APIKEY&channelId=CHANNELID&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20

ex
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=adsjsdakhkjshd&channelId=sdahghsadhgj&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20